# SDK 2.0: Change date field row size without losing edit

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

I'm creating a rally grid for portfolio items using the 2.0 SDK, and including the "PlannedEndDate" field.  This is really nice, because it brings up a calender editor if somebody wants to edit the field.

But I want to make the PlannedEndDate smaller than the standard width.  But, when I do that, I loose the nice editing feature and other defaults.  How do I change the width, but not loose all the other nice defaults?

I'm changing columnCfgs From:

```
PlandEndDate,
```

To:

```
{ dataIndex: 'PlannedEndDate', width: 35, text:'Planned End' }
```

Do I need to use some fancy xtype or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this to your PlannedEndDate column config it should work:

```
editor: {
    xtype: 'rallydatefield',
    format: Rally.util.DateTime.getUserExtDateFormat(),
    validateOnChange: false
}
```

We hope to do some refactoring around the way columns are handled in the grid to make things like this easier.

Comment: Thanks that did it for me.  Yes some refactoring would be great-- I also have to define a renderer, so its a bit messy just to reduce the column size!   Also I think you could perhaps consider just reducing the default size of this column to 100 or so and this would not have come up for me here.  Thanks!